# What is the purpose of transactions that are not marked as inactive due to absence of truncate/log backup?

Tags: sql-server

In full recovery model, log file size keeps growing. When the limit is reached, then the database no longer works.

To ensure this doesn't happen we can either perform truncate or log backup regularly. Either options will ensure the log space can be re-used. It is said that these mark the inactive transactions so that the space can be re-used.

I want to ask - when the above operations (truncate or log backup) are not performed, then aren't the transactions marked inactive? If so then what does it mean to have active transactions - what is their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active transactions are those transactions that are still running on the server, or, those that haven't yet been processed through replication or an Availability Group. They're not marked as inactive because they're still running, and therefore, you really don't want them removed yet. Or, they haven't moved through the process to ensure their data changes get captured, so you really don't want them removed yet. You only want transactions that are truly completed to be purged from the log, preferably, after you backed them up so that you can restore to a point in time and have that restore be consistent.

Comment: So once transaction is fully complete, then why are they not marked as inactive so that the space can be re-used? Why do we have to truncate or take log backups to prevent log size from growing?

Comment: Because you are in full recovery which means that you expect to be able to perform a log backup. If a transaction is removed from the ldf file, you wouldn't be able to do the log backup.

Comment: Yep. What Tibor says. If you're in full recovery, you must take a backup. You really should not be truncating the log while in full recovery. If you need to take more frequent backups to clear out transactions, do that. Truncating means the whole point of being in full recovery, point in time restore, is lost. So, either backup those logs frequently enough, or switch to simple recovery.